# Prove that T is an orthonormal basis if transition matrix from S to T is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

I am having problem trying to prove the following:

> Let S and T be bases for a vector space V , and P be the transition
>   matrix from S to T. Suppose that S is orthonormal.
>
> Please prove that T is an orthonormal basis if P is an orthogonal matrix.

After some research online, all I could find was the proof of the converse: if S is an orthornomal basis, then the transition matrix from S to T is orthogonal.

Nevertheless, here is my attempt:

$$
\text{Let } S = \{ u_1 \cdots u_k \}, T = \{ v_1 \cdots v_k \}
$$
$$
\text{By defintion, } (u_1 \cdots u_k ) = (v_1 \cdots v_k)P
$$

If P is orthogonal, then $P^{T}$ is also orthogonal because column space of P form an orthonormal basis for $ \mathbb{R^n} $.

$\therefore$ By defintion of orthogonal, $ P^{T} = P^{-1} $. Hence $ P ^{-1} $ is also orthogonal.

Thus, $(u_1 \cdots u_k )P^{-1} = (v_1 \cdots v_k)$

I think that I just re-proved the converse of the problem. I can't see how to complete the proof in the other direction. Could someone please advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make notation simpler, let $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be the bases. Form matrices $S$ and $T$ from the respective basis vectors.

Since $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, we have $$PP^T = P^T P =I.$$

Since $\mathcal{S}$ is an orthonormal basis, $S$ is an orthogonal matrix and $$S S^T = S^T S = I.$$

Using that $P$ is the transition matrix from $S$ to $T$,
\begin{align*}
 T &= PS \\
 T^T T &= T^T PS = (PS)^T PS \\
 T^T T &= S^T P^T P S = S^T S = I.
\end{align*}
Similarly, 
\begin{align*}
 T &= PS \\
  TT^T &=  PST^T =  PS (PS)^T\\
  TT^T &=  P SS^T P^T = P^T P = I.
\end{align*}
Since $T^T T = T T^T = I$, we have that $T$ is an orthogonal matrix. Since $T$ was formed from the basis vectors of $\mathcal{T}$, we have that $\mathcal{T}$ is an orthonormal basis.